# php variable variables to access property of an object

Tags: php, object, variable-variables

I want to store an property->object name in a table and access in code.

What is the proper way to accomplish the following.

```
$patient = new stdClass();
$patient->patient_number = '12345';

$cls = 'patient';
$prp = 'patient_number';



echo 'test1 = ' . $patient->patient_number . '<br>';    
//--- this prints 12345 as expected;
echo 'test2 = ' . $$cls->patient_number . '<br>';
//--- this print 12345 as expected;
echo 'test3 = ' . $$cls->${$prp} . '<br>';
//--- this generates undefined variable patient_number;
```

Comment: What has $x and $y got to do with the price of cheese?

Comment: And what is your problem/ question now? Just do: `$$cls->$prp`

Comment: Why should test 3 work?

Comment: Rizier123, that worked great. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
echo 'test3 = ' . ${$cls}->{$prp} . '<br>';
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I just couldn't get the right syntax.